# Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields, Google Map, open only ONE infowindow at a time

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, infowindow, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using google maps addon of Advanced Custom Fields for WordPress.  I have multiple points on the map, some are very close to one another.  I can open open them no problem, however I need to have one open at time.  So if I open one, it closes the others.  The Marker set up on click for advanced custom fields is as follows:

```
if( $marker.html() )
{
    // create info window
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content     : $marker.html(),
        maxWidth: 250
    });


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open( map, marker );
    });     
}
```

Any help on how to append this so only one window is open at a time would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {

/*
*  render_map
*
*  This function will render a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $el (jQuery element)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function render_map( $el ) {

// var
var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

// vars
var args = {
    zoom        : 16,
    center      : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

// create map               
var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);

// add a markers reference
map.markers = [];

// add markers
$markers.each(function(){

    add_marker( $(this), map );

});

// center map
center_map( map );

}

// create info window outside of each - then tell that singular infowindow to swap content based on click
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content     : '' 
});

/*
*  add_marker
*
*  This function will add a marker to the selected Google Map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $marker (jQuery element)
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

// var
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );

// create marker
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position    : latlng,
    map         : map
});

// add to array
map.markers.push( marker );

// if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
if( $marker.html() )
{

    // show info window when marker is clicked & close other markers
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        //swap content of that singular infowindow
                infowindow.setContent($marker.html());
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    // close info window when map is clicked
         google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            if (infowindow) {
                infowindow.close(); }
            }); 

}

}

/*
*  center_map
*
*  This function will center the map, showing all markers attached to this map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function center_map( map ) {

// vars
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

// loop through all markers and create bounds
$.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );

    bounds.extend( latlng );

});

// only 1 marker?
if( map.markers.length == 1 )
{
    // set center of map
    map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
    map.setZoom( 16 );
}
else
{
    // fit to bounds
    map.fitBounds( bounds );
}

}

/*
*  document ready
*
*  This function will render each map when the document is ready (page has loaded)
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   5.0.0
*
*  @param   n/a
*  @return  n/a
*/

$(document).ready(function(){

$('.acf-map').each(function(){

    render_map( $(this) );

});

});

})(jQuery);
</script>
```